# Объясните пример кода из django

Tags: python, django

Есть некоторый код:

```py
#nameApp/url.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:rubric_id>/', by_rubric),
]
```

также, еще это:

```py
# nameApp/views.py
def by_rubric(request, rubric_id):
    bbs = Bb.object.filter(rubric=rubric_id)
    rubrics = Rubric.objects.all()
    current_rubric = Rubric.objects.get(pk=rubric_id)
    context = {
        'bbs': bbs, 
        'rubrics' : rubrics,
        'current_rubric': current_rubric,
    }
    return render(request, 'bboard/ by_rubric . html', context)
```

В книге написано:

> `rubric_id` - имя параметра контроллера, которому будет присвоено значение этого URL-параметра.

Я не понимаю как и какое значение попадает в этот url параметр.

Comment: Такое, которое пользователь передаст в URL'е запроса.

Answer (score 5):

в urls.py
ты прописываешь маршруты для твоего приложения
например то, что ты прописал
`path('<int:rubric_id>/', by_rubric),`

означает что когда пользователь будет переходить по страницам вида
`www.your-site.com/10/`
`www.your-site.com/11/`
...
то у тебя будет вызываться view `by_rubric` и в параметре `rubic_id` будут передаваться значения (10,11 из url страницы которую открыл пользователь)

подробней про конфигурацию url можно найти в документации
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#module-django.urls.conf

Answer (score 1):

К примеру есть ссылка http://yoursite/article/id-article

И то, что будет вместо  `id-article` получит ваш параметр функции и преобразован в тот тип, что указан в `urls.py`

Answer (score 1):

Первое и самое основное, что я тебе посоветую, так это закрыть или лучше сожги книгу дронова и забудь о ней как страшный сон.

Лучше почитай книгу Антонио Меле, она тоже далека от идеала, но по крайней мере в ней меньше говнокода.

Касательно твоего вопроса:

rubric_id - это что-то, что может передаваться твоей функции, когда ты переходишь по ссылке.

В данной строке **current_rubric = Rubric.objects.get(pk=rubric_id)** ты получаешь id объекта категории. pk - это id, и тут (pk=rubric_id) мы получаем этот самый id, можно записать и так : (id=rubric_id)